# Сохранение типов во время компиляции

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, компиляция, constexpr

Я пытаюсь реализовать обертку над чем-то подобным:

```
template <typename ...Type>
struct Types
{
    template <typename NewType>
    constexpr auto addType()
    {
        return Types<Type..., NewType>();
    }

    template<size_t n>
    constexpr auto getType()
    {
        return std::get<n+1>(types);
    }

    static constexpr std::variant<std::monostate, Type...> types {};
};
```

То есть моя цель, чтоб в зависимости от вызовов функции addType(), я в итоге как-то получил  доступ к std::variant (std::tuple тоже устроит), для которого я смогу вызвать getType().
По идее же все типы, которые я добавляю, известны во время компиляции? Есть вариант как-то реализовать нечто подобное?

Вариант хранить список std::type_info мне не подходит.

Comment: Пожалуйста приведите пример использования предполагаемого шаблона, или опишите задачу более высокого уровня (при решении которой вы столкнулись с данной проблемой).  Сейчас непонятно, чего вы пытаетесь добиться. Вызовы addType сейчас не меняют статической переменой, а создают новую (вместе с новым типом).

Comment: Я понимаю. В этом и проблема. Мне как-то надо хранить новый объект, который я получаю. То есть сейчас я могу сделать только так:    auto t1 = Types<int>();
    auto t2 = t1.addType<double>();
    std::cout <<  typeid(t2.getType<1>()).name();. Моя цель избежать создания новых переменных каждый раз, а как-то хранить в одной.

Comment: Все равно непонятно. Вы хотите хранить значение, или только тип? Как именно хотите использовать "идеальный" шаблон, а не тот который есть сейчас. Вас не устраивает что требуется порождать новый тип `t2`? Вас не устраивает что приходится работать с переменными определенных типов, хотя по смыслу нужно с типами непосредственно?

Comment: Грубо говоря, мне нужно, чтобы после компиляции, был какой-то объект, в котором будут по аналогии примера храниться типы (не std::type_info) Например, в примере я храню в std::variant. Список этих типов должен быть определен не в момент создания такого объекта, а с учетом всех вызовов addType<NewType>();. Вопрос в том, возможно ли реализовать такой механизм?

Comment: это невозможно. Тип -  сущность времени компиляции. Он может храниться только в виде параметра щаблона или typedef. Т.е. не может меняться в результате вызова функции, кроме как порождением нового типа.

Comment: Понял, спасибо за ответ. Но почему так, ведь инстанцирование шаблонов тоже происходит во время компиляции. Почему же нет способов, исходя из этого, как-то накапливать информацию о выховах addType и создать std::variant с нужным набором типов?

Comment: [Способы-то есть](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/fceeqMzEh), но это страшные костыли. Можете пояснить, зачем вам это нужно?